# How to add/manage multiple image size/resolution in flutter assets

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, assets, image-size, image-resolution

Kindly help with the simplest/shortest way

wish to manage multiple images in flutter like hdpi/mdpi... in Android studio

How do I include image assets for Flutter? What about multiple resolutions?

Comment: Have you read - https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#declaring-resolution-aware-image-assets ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Declaring resolution aware image assets
Source - https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#resolution-aware

> AssetImage understands how to map a logical requested asset onto one
>   that most closely matches the current device pixel ratio. In order for
>   this mapping to work, assets should be arranged according to a
>   particular directory structure:
>
> ```
> content_copy
>   .../image.png
>   .../Mx/image.png
>   .../Nx/image.png
>   ...etc.
> ```
>
> …where M and N are numeric identifiers that correspond to the nominal
>   resolution of the images contained within, in other words, they
>   specify the device pixel ratio that the images are intended for.
>
> The main asset is assumed to correspond to a resolution of 1.0. For
>   example, consider the following asset layout for an image named
>   my_icon.png:
>
> ```
> content_copy
>   .../my_icon.png
>   .../2.0x/my_icon.png
>   .../3.0x/my_icon.png
> ```
>
> On devices with a device pixel ratio of 1.8, the asset
>   .../2.0x/my_icon.png would be chosen. For a device pixel ratio of 2.7,
>   the asset .../3.0x/my_icon.png would be chosen.
>
> If the width and height of the rendered image are not specified on the
>   Image widget, the nominal resolution is used to scale the asset so
>   that it will occupy the same amount of screen space as the main asset
>   would have, just with a higher resolution. That is, if .../my_icon.png
>   is 72px by 72px, then .../3.0x/my_icon.png should be 216px by 216px;
>   but they both will render into 72px by 72px (in logical pixels) if
>   width and height are not specified.
>
> Each entry in the asset section of the pubspec.yaml should correspond
>   to a real file, with the exception of the main asset entry. If the
>   main asset entry does not correspond to a real file, then the asset
>   with the lowest resolution will be used as the fallback for devices
>   with device pixel ratios below that resolution. The entry should still
>   be included in the pubspec.yaml manifest, however.